# Check if an integer array has for every value n in the array, there is also an element 2n, 2n+1, n/2. Return 1 if it satisfies and 0 if it doesn't

Tags: java, arrays

I appeared in an online test. This is the code I have written which got rejected, what issues do you see? sample inputs are {4,9,8} should give 1 as for 4, 8 is present, for 9, 4 is present, for 8,4 is present. But {3,8,4} should return 0 as because 3 requires either 6,7 or 1 and none of these values are in array. Similarly, {2,2,5,11,23},{7,7,3,6},{0} would return 1 as it satisfies the condition. I have checked for these sample inputs and the code works perfectly for these but I am not being able find why the code was rejected. I may be missing to think something from different perspective. Please help!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = {4,9,8}; 
    System.out.println(isBean(arr));
}
public static int isBean(int []a)
{
    int next1=0;
    int next2=0;
    int next3=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        int n =a[i];
        next1 = 2*n;
        next2 =2*n+1;
        next3= n/2;
        boolean isValid = false;
        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]==next1 || a[j]==next2 || a[j]==next3)
            {
                isValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!isValid)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post your full question with sample input and output

Comment: Not sure what the requirement here is! Best to debug the code.

Comment: Please add to the int[] you are using to test the code please

Comment: I have edited the question and added few inputs and outputs that the code satisfies already. May be something is there that I have been missing to think

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  please check I have added sample inputs and outputs

Comment: @SkyWalker Please check, I have added sample inputs and outputs

Answer (score 0):

Actually this type of problem need necessary things

1. Number of array element
2. Array Element
3. Conditions
4. Input Sample
5. Output Sample

### Code Details

```
import java.util.*;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfArrayElement = inp.nextInt();
//      System.out.println(numberOfArrayElement);
        int[] arr = new int[numberOfArrayElement];
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArrayElement; i++) {
            val = inp.nextInt();
            arr[i] = val;
        }
//      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArrayElement; i++) {
//          System.out.println(arr[i]);
//      }
        System.out.println(isBean(arr));
    }

    public static int isBean(int[] a) {
        int next1 = 0;
        int next2 = 0;
        int next3 = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int n = a[i];
            next1 = 2 * n;
            next2 = 2 * n + 1;
            next3 = n / 2;
            boolean isValid = false;
//          System.out.println("================================");
//          System.out.println(a[i]);
//          System.out.println(next1);
//          System.out.println(next2);
//          System.out.println(next3);
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j] == next1 || a[j] == next2 || a[j] == next3) {
                    isValid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isValid) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        // System.out.println("length of array: " + a.length);
        if (counter == a.length)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

### Sample Input#1:

3

4
9
8

### Sample Output#1

1

### Sample Input#2:

5

2
2
5
11
23

### Sample Output#2

1

### Sample Input#3:

1

2

### Sample Output#3

0

Comment: I got your idea of using counter to check if all the element satisfied the condition. But my code returns 0 as soon as it reaches a single element in the array that doesn't satisfy the condition, otherwise it reaches up to the end and returns 1 if all the elements satisfies. This sounds even more efficient to me. So what issue do you see in my code. Any logical error or something else or anything?

Comment: Actually, there are some issues. 1. input will be dynamic. 2. some boundary condition is given so you must have to check those issues are maintained or not. 3.  Multiple input is allowed or not etc etc. And another thing: you can use any efficient algorithm for your coding. @pari

Comment: 1. Asking input from user was not necessary. 2. what boundary condition is there that I have left, could you please help me to learn?Please elaborate what am I missing? 3. Multiple inputs are not necessary. My code should check " if the given input of integer array satisfies that for every value n in the array, there is also an element 2n, 2n+1, or n/2. If yes return 1, if no return 0." Please help me if you find any bug in my code that doesn't satisfy this condition.